# Ruby writing into several files on a loop does not give expected answer

Tags: ruby

I have some ruby code that should execute and create some files with outputs in it.

When i run the code a single time i don't have any problems at all, but when i try to run it on a loop the first file comes out with a normal output, but from the second file foward, they all follow a bizarre pattern.

If i run it three times the first output comes normal, the second comes with the info of the first followed by the output it should have and the third one comes with the first and the second output first and then it's normal output.

This is the code i use to read file:

```
File.open(path, 'rb') { |file| file.read }
```

This is the code i use to write on file:

```
 File.open(path + '.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.write text
 end
```

This is a part of the code i'm using to run it multiple times:

```
while i < 4 do
    sample_path = "#{path}/samples/sample#{i}.html.erb"
    controller_grabber.grab_controllers(sample_path)
    answer_string = file_manager.read_file("#{path}/samples/sample#{i}_expected_answer.txt").gsub(/\s+/, "")
    tool_answer = file_manager.read_file("#{path}/outputs/#{file_manager.get_file_name(sample_path)}_output.txt").gsub(/\s+/, "")
    i += 1
end
```

On grab_controllers i call write file once. I really have no idea what the cause might be, tried to create a new instance of controller_grabber and file_manager but it didn't worked

Here is some example of the outputs i'm getting

First expected result:

```
[name: Show, type: @otml_file]
[name: Back, type: otml_files_path]
```

Result:

```
[name: Show, type: @otml_file]
[name: Back, type: otml_files_path]
```

Second expected result:

```
[name: Inicio, type: root_path]
[name: Producto, type: productos_index_path]
[name: Venta, type: venta_index_path]
[name: Proveedor, type: proveedor_index_path]
[name: Clientes, type: cliente_index_path]
```

Second result:

```
[name: Show, type: @otml_file]
[name: Back, type: otml_files_path]
[name: Inicio, type: root_path]
[name: Producto, type: productos_index_path]
[name: Venta, type: venta_index_path]
[name: Proveedor, type: proveedor_index_path]
[name: Clientes, type: cliente_index_path]
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems bananas.  I'm guessing you have a lingering reference to the file in some of the code that is omitted - it's hard to see with the current amount of code.

When I read, write, read in a loop, I get what you would expect:

```
path = 'filename'
text = 'something'

10.times {
  p File.open(path, 'rb') { |file| file.read }

  result = File.open(path, 'w+') do |f|
    f.write text
  end

  p result

  p File.open(path, 'rb') { |file| file.read }
}
```

If you are certain you want to overwrite the file on each pass, then you should probably [delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-delete) the file each time through.

Or give them different names...

Maybe with more info I can be more helpful.